# Will Cassandra leave my party?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

This question may contain spoilers from after the mission "Wicked Eyes and Wicked Hearts".

> I've just completed the mission and back at Skyhold I learned that Leliana or Cassandra are in consideration for the new divine. I'd like to support Cassandra, but she is the main tank in my party and I've taken her with me the entire game.
>  I made a careful google search, trying not to get spoiled too much, and found a few suggestions that she does leave the party but I found nothing concrete. Someone also suggested that there is a way through dialogue to get her back into the party again, but I found no reliable source.
>  I'd like to know whether she would leave for good at some point or if I can still choose to have her fighting with me.

Please keep an answer as spoiler-free as possible or use the spoiler tag.

Comment: I couldn't do more paragraphs in the spoiler tag without it showing the text for some reason, so there's a small wall of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoever you support will become a new Divine only after you finish the main storyline. The epilogue scene will mention about the new Divine.

So don't worry if they will leave your party. If they do so, only after you finish the main storyline. 
In the spoiler tag are Leliana and Cassandra situation after the main storyline.

> Post game: 
>  - If Leliana is the new Divine: She is still in the Inquisition and she says they were still making arrangements and she could help the Inquisition in the mean time. 
>  - If Cassandra is the new Divine: She begs you to let her come along with you on more adventures. You can choose whether or not to let her back into your party.

Answer (score 2):

cassandra will leave the party briefly then just go talk to her in skyhold again and she will state that she is bored out of her mind and ask to rejoin your party